# How to make cortana search box dark

Tags: windows-10, themes, cortana

It used to always be dark for me, now after updating my machine (yesterday) it has been white (light), and it's really annoying:

[image]

I realized that if I make it *Dark Mode* then it looks normal, however I don't like dark mode for everything else.

[image]

The search box used to always be dark (Even though I've always been in light mode)

---

I've also found [this page on Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/cortana-search-box-is-white/219911c9-fdb0-4da9-af97-262ecf8e18c4?auth=1), however, I couldn't find much other than Dark mode.

### Update:

I tried messing with the registry and this is what I got:

[image]

Note how it's also not aligned properly... either way it switched back after a restart. Guess I'm gonna have to wait for Microsoft to fix this, arghh

Answer (score 3):

With the current theme support on Windows 10 (Fall Creators Update, build 1709) the only option is to use the Dark Mode.

Microsoft is reportedly building the systems to handle a robust theme engine which should appear in the next major update to Windows 10.

But right now, fall of 2017, this is not possible.